# How to use @Parcelize field in @Serializable data class in Android kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, data-class

I have a data class declared with below properties.

```
@Parcelize
data class Sample(
val name: String = ""
) : Parcelable
```

I want to use above data class in below data class.

```
@Serializable
data class Main(
val sample: Sample
)
```

If i use like above code, getting null.
Is there way to access both the way data classes combined in android kotlin?

Comment: Serializable doesn’t know anything about Parcelable. Why not make them both Parcelable?

Comment: Don't mix the two of those.  They work just fine with themselves, but aren't really made to work with each other.